# Android Studio can't access SDK Manager

Tags: sdk, android-studio

I have just downloaded and installed Android studio 0.4.2 and loaded an android project.  This project gives me this error:

```
Cause: failed to find target android-17
       Please install the missing platform from the Android SDK Manager.
```

so great, I will now go into the SDK manager, and get the missing platform.  The only problem is, I cannot access the SDK Manager.  The SDK manager button is grayed out and when I go to tools, there is no option for android, so I can't go to toold

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?  I have used Eclipse with ADT before and never had this issue...

Answer (score 24):

Close the project from

```
File > Close project
```

doing this will take ou to the Android Studio welcome screen. From there navigate to this path

```
Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure > Android SDK
```

Set you Android SDK location here, you can check all API's level from he same screen inside SDKs tab.

Now import your project again. You can set project specific SDK after opening the project from

```
File > Project Structure
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old one, but since I fixed that, I'm just sharing. 
I sorted it downloading the stand-alone SDK and pointing the SDK Location to the folder.

- Download the SDK from the "Get the SDK for an existing IDE" https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- As @pyus13 said, from the Project structure, select the downloaded folder

Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure > Android SDK

- Now your SDK Manager tab in no longer grayed out and you can access it

Hope this help.

Comment: AS 3.1 I clicked Prefs / Search = sdk and finally I can open it without a project. ty!

Answer (score 0):

I found the bulls eye solution.

1. Download SDK zip file from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Copy and paste that extracted folder into Applications/Android Studio/
4. Open Android Studio. Go to: (Quick Start) / Configure / Project Defaults / Project Structure / (Android SDK Location) and browse SDK folder.
5. Apply and save.

You and me finally solved this problem. :D