# Android Studio not showing SDK Manager Option in the Tools Menu

Tags: android

In Android Studio when I select the Tools Option, The SDK Manager Option is not shown.

Also, when I search for SDK Manager using the Search Option it shows the SDK Manager Option, but when i click on it nothing happens.

So, what should I do to install new packages from the SDK Manager.

Comment: go in windows-> sdk manager

Comment: windows is not showing any sdk manager option.I re-installed the android studio software multiple times, but having the same problem.

Comment: Same here. Freshly installed Android Studio v3.1.3 (without any problem indication) but Tools => SDK Manager and Tools => AVD Manager not showing up. 4 Android-something plugins that are listed are all enabled. So, when trying to start my app and it comes to select the device to run it: dead end... :-(

Comment: Per an answer below, you need to go View => Toolbar. Then the SDK Manager looks like a cube in the toolbar that pops up. Still no checkbox to simply accept the license. There's no excuse for Android making this process so unintuitive. I can't recall it taking an hour to figure out how to accept a license in any other environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this as follows:

```
Window > Customize Perspective... (you will see Android and AVD Manager are disabled)

Command Groups Availability > Android and AVD Manager > check

Tool Bar Visibility > Android and AVD Manager > check
```

Comment: when i search customize perspective in windows, it is loading some images.

Comment: Window>Customize Perspective is available in eclipse but Android Studio is using Intellij IDE.

Comment: just see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313829/android-studio-cant-access-sdk-manager

Answer (score 27):

Go to  Menu bar click -> View button and Select -> Toolbar

Thats it.

Thanks

Comment: This is what works for Android Studio. The accepted answer might work for Eclipse only.

Comment: Gee. Why not just put it in Tools where the documentation says it is: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

Answer (score 10):

In Android studio 4.0.1 it is on right, directly on panel.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

check if android support is checked in pluggins

Comment: and if it is, uncheck and check it again

Answer (score 2):

I installed android studio 3.4 and even i could not see the sdk manager under tools. There are two ways to get to SDK manager:

1. From the start screen of android studio (popup, where you select a blank project or any other existing project), there is a configure button at the bottom right of the popup. Click that and you would see the option for SDK Manager.
2. From toolbar Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK  ( or in preferences window search box type 'sdk' and you will goto this path directly).

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of Android Studio You can find the sdk manager option on the top right corner. just beside the search option.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same problem and am not finding this solution works.  Perhaps this solution solves some cases where the SDK Manager Option is not shown.  But, I think there are others.

I strongly recommend avoiding Android Studio at this time.  It's a beta project and as such ... not intended to work as expected.