# Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.- 20.1.5948944 NDK (Side by side) 20.1.5948944

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I have taken a pull from bitbucket and trying to run a project. While running the project it says the following lines:

```
ERROR: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
   ndk;20.1.5948944 NDK (Side by side) 20.1.5948944
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
```

Android studio is also installed new in the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install Android Studio 3.5.2, the android studio doesn't install NDK(Side By side) so, you need to do it manually. Tools -> SDK Manager -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> (Select) SDK Tool and enable NDK(Side by Side).

Comment: If your issue is solved. you can update your question.

Comment: Update with what? Sorry I am unaware of the rules of stackoverflow so, I don't know what has to be updated.

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio has detected that your project requires the NDK (Native Development Kit - for C/C++ code building), but you don't have the NDK installed.

It was detected because you probably have something like this in your **`app/build.gradle`** file:

```js
android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

More info:

- https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.4/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeBuild.html

You'll need to manually install the Android NDK tool, which is a large 930 MB download:

1. Android Studio ➔ File ➔ **Settings** (Windows/Linux). Or Android Studio ➔ **Preferences** (MacOS)
2. In the search box, type in **"sdk"** and navigate to **Languages & Frameworks ➔ Android SDK**. (Some Android Studio versions have this in **Appearance and Behavior ➔ System Settings ➔ Android SDK**)
3. Click the **'SDK Tools'** tab
4. Optional: You may want to click on **"Show Package Details"** at the bottom-right, in order to choose a specific version of the NDK.
5. Click the checkbox for **"NDK (Side by Side)"**

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio ➔ Preferences ➔ Appearance and Behavior ➔ System Settings ➔ Android SDK]

5. Click the **Apply** button. This will download the Android NDK for you.
6. Then do a gradle sync: Press the 'elephant' icon at the far right, with tooltip **"Sync Project With Gradle Files"**

[image: Android Studio toolbar - Button: Sync Project with Gradle Files]

You may be prompted to install **CMake** next. Just follow the same process to install CMake. Or click the blue link in Build window: "Install CMake 3.XX.X". You should now be able to build your project.

Once you've installed the NDK and CMake and configured it, you should see new menu options for **Android Studio ➔ Tools ➔ SDK Manager** and **AVD Manager**.

Answer (score 0):

See also:
[Android Studio not showing SDK Manager Option in the Tools Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948652/android-studio-not-showing-sdk-manager-option-in-the-tools-menu)
(the SDK manager not always is accessible from "Tools" drop-down menu)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and I could solve it by adding this line code in the **build.gridle** inside of Android{} block

### ndkVersion "21.0.6113669"

Then sync project.

Comment: me too, can not install version 21.0.6113669. Have you solved?