# Android folder under tools is missing in android studio

Tags: android, settings

I want to open SDK manager in android studio to update cmake folder. There is no cmake folder.So, I tried opening tools->Android->SDK manager.
But there is no android option under tools

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40410122/671393

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

Delete your ~/.Android* folders (losing all of your settings :/).
Run Android Studio. It will show you a welcome wizard where it tries to download the SDK again (and fails due to my rubbish internet).

Click the X on the wizard window. That will enable you to get to the normal welcome dialog.

Go to Settings->Project Defaults->Project Structure and change the Android SDK location to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar situation when I updated android studio and deleted original SDK folder. Although SDK manager is not visible in your tools tab, you are still able to launch here

```
File -> Setting -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Setting -> Android SDK
```

SDK manager button will be visible after you installed platform version which `build.gradle` is targeting.