# unable to run standalone android sdk manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, android-studio-2.3

Today i upgraded to android studio 2.3 and found out that standalone sdk manager can not be launched from android studio anymore. So i went to C:\Users\Fahim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iaYr.png) and tried to run SDK Manager.exe by double clicking and run as administrator. A black window flashes for a moment and disappears and the sdk manager is not launched.
I always ran sdk manager from android studio in the past.
I'm using windows 7. This is the Path environment variable

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Users\Fahim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Users\Fahim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32
```

If anyone knows what the problem is please help me.

Comment: it may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313829/android-studio-cant-access-sdk-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the standalone SDK manager has been deprecated, you should use the one within android studio.